# I am trying to see map in fragment which is causing null exception

Tags: android, google-maps

My Requirement:

I have used Bottom Navigation in a class, This intent is called from Maninclass after successfully sign in. In BottomNavigation I have four options in which one is to show CurrentLocation of user. I have used fragments.I have almost tried all the options available in search but could not succeed. please help me.

Fragemnet class:

```
public class HomeFragment extends SupportMapFragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("came to home" ,"create");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view , Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("came to home" ,"created");
        onResume();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i("came to home" ,"resime");
        onMapReady(mGoogleMap);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}

    BottomNavigation Class:


package com.americanexpress.developer.rideblue;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.americanexpress.developer.rideblue.fragments.BottomNVFragment;
import com.americanexpress.developer.rideblue.fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.americanexpress.developer.rideblue.fragments.*;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;

public class BottomNavigation extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    GoogleSignInAccount account;
    HomeFragment mapFragment;
    Bundle data ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("in bottom","inten2");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_navigation);


        mapFragment = new HomeFragment();


        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        data = new Bundle();

        //loading the default fragment
        //loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

        BottomNavigationView bnv = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        bnv.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                methodForHomeFragment();

                break;

            case R.id.navigation_account:
                methodForAccountFragment();

                break;

            case R.id.navigation_trips:
                methodForTripsFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                methodForNotificationFragment();
                break;


        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);

    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
   /*     if (fragment != null && (!fragment.equals(new HomeFragment()))) {

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }else {
            Log.i("comming to methd", "home");
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.mapframe, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;

        }*/

        if (fragment != null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;


    }

    public void methodForAccountFragment() {
        fragment = new AccountFragment();



        String  userName = String.valueOf(account.getDisplayName());
        data.putString("username", userName);
        fragment.setArguments(data);

        String  userGmail = String.valueOf(account.getEmail());
        data.putString("usergmail", userGmail);
        fragment.setArguments(data);

        String imageURL = String.valueOf(account.getPhotoUrl());
        data.putString("imageurl", imageURL);
        fragment.setArguments(data);

        String tokenID = String.valueOf(account.getIdToken());
        data.putString("tokenID", tokenID);
        fragment.setArguments(data);


    }


    public void methodForTripsFragment() {
        fragment = new TripsFragment();


        //     String  token = String.valueOf(account.getIdToken());

        // method to get trip details



    }

    public void methodForNotificationFragment() {
        fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
        //     String  token = String.valueOf(account.getIdToken());
        // method to show notifications like thanks messages to the user


    }

    public void methodForHomeFragment() {
        fragment = new HomeFragment();

        //      String  token = String.valueOf(account.getIdToken());
        // method to show notifications like thanks messages to the user


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == HomeFragment.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION){
            mapFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
        else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call onMapReady by yourself in the onResume .. wait until the map is ready .. and you will find the onMapReady called as a callback ..

```
public void onResume() {
    Log.i("came to home" ,"resime");
    onMapReady(mGoogleMap);
}
```